# Why does it take so long to recover from a terminated program that had consumed all memory?

Tags: windows-7, memory, freeze

Every once in a while I run a certain program (MATLAB) and it takes up too much memory. At this stage the physical mem is at ~100% and the computer barely works.

I then terminate MATLAB and I can see the memory is freed on the task manager (image).

However, it takes about 5-10 minutes until I have full control over my computer back. In these 10 minutes the computer gradually becomes usable, open programs get 'unfrozen', etc.

I guess that if MATLAB consumed all the memory then some other program's data was saved in the swap mem, but is it okay for this process of 'recovery' to take such a long time?

I'm using Windows 7 with intel i5-2500 and 12GB RAM.

[image]

Comment: Are you terminating Matlab using its menu system or by a forced shutdown via task manager?  If task manager, it gets busy creating a crash report, which I have always observed takes time.

Comment: Using the task man. But the '10 minute recovery' happens after termination and when the MATLAB.exe process disappears from the active processes. Is it possible that it keeps on running even if I can see it on the task manager processes?

Comment: I assume your last sentence should be "even if I cannot see it..."  IIRC, when I use the task mgr to kill a program, it takes a little while to kill and then it prepares a crash report that it asks to send to Microsoft.  I believe that the crash report preparation takes a fair bit of CPU, so affects the responsiveness of the machine.  Your image is not consistent with that -- it shows low CPU throughout the time frame and a drop in RAM utilization at the same time.